# How to set value of a DataGridView Cell programatically?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to clear the cell if certain conditions are met. But its not working.

**UPDATE**

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
        Dim laspac As Int16 = DataGridView1.Columns("LASPAC").Index

        If e.ColumnIndex = laspac And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CType").Value.ToString.Trim() = "B" Then
            Dim B_LASPAC As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LASPAC")
            Dim A_LASPAC As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex - 1).Cells("LASPAC")
            If B_LASPAC.Value.ToString.Trim.Length <> 0 Then

                If Convert.ToDecimal(B_LASPAC.Value) + Convert.ToDecimal(A_LASPAC.Value) > 0 Then

                    B_LASPAC.Value = ""


                End If
            End If


        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Dr. Freud acknowledges your title :)

Comment: What does "its not working" exactly mean? Do you get any error? Does it not work under certain conditions/never?, etc.

Comment: It does not give me any error .. it just doesnt work. Never.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I am not really sure what that means but seems like a good comment to me :)

Comment: OK. Your code is a bit intrincate and you might have included some errors while building it. The maximum we can do is building a clear and for-sure-performing-the-actions-you-want version (although without the right inputs it will not work anyway...). Can you please describe clearly the behaviour you are trying to track? Example: when the cell in column "X" is numeric and its value is... I want to trigger the msgbox.

Comment: Is the datagridview bound to a dataset?

Comment: @ZL1Corvette yes why?\

Comment: I was having issues with the changes not making it to the dataset in my own project. I thought maybe you were having the same problem, but your's appears to be something along the lines of the code is running but the draw event or something is updating before the new value is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, just pass the **RowIndex** and **ColumnIndex**

eg.

```
Dim rowId = 0
Dim colId = 1

DataGridView1(colId, rowId).Value = "HELLO"
```

so, in your case... something like

```
If ... Then
    DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: please check my update... it works but it works only when i go back to the cell and leave again

Comment: @Arbaaz why are you handling the CellLeave event?

Comment: then what event should I use?

Comment: @Arbaaz it depends, when do you want to change the value of that cell?

Comment: Preferably on cell leave.

Comment: @Arbaaz so, when you leave cell A, cell B.Value will be changed?

Comment: the thing is there are two kinds of rows 
A comes before B  I am taking value of a cell of row A and B and comparing them ... (Only Row B is editable, A is readonly) If sum of both is greater than 0 I will clear the cell A which was entered by the user as soon as he leaves that cell of row A

Comment: I just realized that when I type a value say 10000 and then leave the cell... The ` B_LASPAC.Value` evaluated to be blank! It is only the second time when enter and leave the cell again that I get  `10000` value in  `B_LASPAC.Value`

Comment: I have managed to solve it finally... 
btw +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `B_LASPAC.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()` instead of `B_LASPAC.Value.ToString()` to get the value of the cell on cell leave and also I realized that I need to end the EditMode of the DataGridView by using `DataGridView1.EndEdit()`  just before I set the new value of the cell `B_LASPAC.Value = ""`

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
        Dim laspac As Int16 = DataGridView1.Columns("LASPAC").Index

        If e.ColumnIndex = laspac And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CType").Value.ToString.Trim() = "B" Then
            Dim B_LASPAC As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LASPAC")
            Dim A_LASPAC As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex - 1).Cells("LASPAC")
            Dim str As String = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("LASPAC").EditedFormattedValue.ToString()
            If B_LASPAC.EditedFormattedValue.ToString.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
                If Convert.ToDecimal(B_LASPAC.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()) + Convert.ToDecimal(A_LASPAC.EditedFormattedValue.ToString()) > 0 Then

                    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
                    B_LASPAC.Value = ""

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```