# How do I change the value of a specific DataGridView Cell?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I've been trying to add a feature to my program that allows you to choose a file using OpenFileDialog (when you double click on a DataGridView cell) and change the value of that cell to the path of the file you chose. I have no idea what the command is to do that. I've tried to guess and I looked up on the internet and couldn't find anything.

```
Private Sub dgSound_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgSound.CellDoubleClick

    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then 'Index of "file" column
        Dim file As String = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        file = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        'Contents of cell that was clicked = file          

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: `e` passed to the event has some row/col information in it to tell which was clicked.

Comment: @Plutonix I know that, but I don't know the specific command to change that cell.

Comment: `dgSound(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = "Whatever Goes Here"`

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks! I didn't expect to be that easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set value of a DataGridView Cell programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969453/how-to-set-value-of-a-datagridview-cell-programatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `CellClick` rather than `CellContentClick` as follows...

```
  Private Sub dgSound_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgSound.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then 'Index of "file" column
      Dim file As String = ""
      OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
      file = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

      'Contents of cell that was clicked = file          
      dgSound.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = file

    End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not using CellContentClick, I'm using CellDoubleClick. Thanks for your answer!